# How to autoscale Docker container hosts?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, autoscaling

I'm developing a Docker-based web service, where each subscriber has private access to their own Docker container running in the cloud, exposing port 443.

I've used [nginx-proxy/docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) successfully to serve multiple Docker containers from the same VM, with just port 443 exposed to the public net.

This works fine ... but what do I do when the subscribers saturate the VM resources?
(As a simple example, I may have a practical limit of 10 subscribers' containers on a single DigitalOcean 2Gb instance serving as a Docker host.)

Eg when subscriber #11 signs up, I need to have a new Docker host ready and waiting to start up that new container.

In other words, I want to do **horizontal autoscaling** of my Docker hosts, responsive to user subscription demand. Doing some service discovery and making the containers publicly-addressable would be nice.

I'm trying to work out what the best solution is. Kubernetes 1.1 seems to support auto-scaling of Pods (ie basically increasing the number of containers...) but not the auto-scaling of the container hosts ("minions" in Kubernetes-speak??)

I've looked at the following projects which seem close to what I need:

- [Deis](http://deis.io/) - no explicit autoscaling as far as I can tell
- [Tsuru](http://tsuru.io) - possible autoscaling solution but limited to count/RAM
- [Mesos/Mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/) - probably much more complex than necessary

Can anybody make any useful suggestions??

Comment: I don't know an existing solution for you right now. But there is some discussion of how/when to add the feature to Kubernetes (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/15304 as a starting point).

Comment: Auto scaling the hosts is very dependent on what cloud you're running Kubernetes upon. For example on Openstack you can run Kubernetes via Murano or Magnum. In both cases they're using a Heat template, coupled with Celiometer alerts to auto scale the underlying VMs running Kubernetes.

Comment: @rwehner: That looks interesting - looks like basic cluster autoscaling will be in Kubernetes 1.2 ? Well that will likely be quite a while from now I guess ... so I can't use Kubernetes on its own right now ...

Comment: @MarkO'Connor , thanks very much for the hints here. I'm intending to run on "barebones" cloud servers (DigitalOcean/Linode etc) and set up all services myself. I had thought that setting up Openstack myself might be over-engineering (like using Mesos/Mesosphere) but if I can do a basic production deployment without too much of a resource overhead (ie how many machines do I need to just run basic Openstack services?) then it could be the right option.
Though it's quite a lot of tech in the stack.... Openstack+Magnum/Murano+Kubernetes ... hmmmm...

Comment: @danzvash The Magnum and Murano solutions are intended to deploy Kubernetes differently. The first is a proper "Container as a service" offering where Kubernetes in an option, the second installs it as an application. Under the hood they're both using Heat to orchestrate the Openstack API calls. The auto-scaling feature is something provided by Heat (based on Ceilometer metrics). On other clouds there may be similar offers to Heat. For example on Amazon there's cloud formation.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, appreciate the clarification. I've been checking out Magnum in particular. I did see some commenters saying that Ceilometer (with MongoDB backend) was not performant or stable - but those may have been old comments ... I'm hoping! The Openstack suite you describe does seem to be my best hope .... as long as the production deployment isn't too overweight.
Thanks again!

Comment: @danzvash Did you find a way to achieve this horizontal autoscaling? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of Kubernetes v1.1, you can now implement a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html

Comment: Thanks, but actually it was specifically the node autoscaling which I was looking for. rwehner already referenced the feature above which is due for inclusion in Kubernetes 1.2. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/cluster-management.md#horizontal-auto-scaling-of-nodes-gce